# Rails and Postgres, group by hstore

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

I have an 'Audit' model with name:string and data:hstore attributes - as follows:

```
#<Audit 
id: 1, 
name: "my audit", 
data: {"publisher"=>"some publisher",  "display_version"=>"17.012.20098"}, 
created_at: "2017-10-10 13:09:56", 
updated_at: "2017-10-10 13:09:56">
```

I want to produce a report that contains 3 columns:
name, display_version, count

To achieve this I assume that I need to group by "name" and "data -> 'display_version'"

I am struggling with the query and AR syntax.

What I have so far is:

```
Parent.audits.group(:name, :data -> 'display_version)'
```

Even this doesn't work. Can someone help? I have searched for examples without any luck.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a string containing the SQL grouping expression to [`group`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-group) so you could say:

```
Parent.audits.group(%q{name, data -> 'display_version'})
```

or:

```
Parent.audits.group(%q{audits.name, audits.data -> 'display_version'})
```

And then you could throw a `#count` call on the end to get the data you want:

```
Parent.audits.group(%q{name, data -> 'display_version'}).count
```

Comment: Thanks. This yields: ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::GroupingError: ERROR:  column "audits.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

Comment: Sorry, missed the `count`. I just updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use `jsonb` instead of `hstore` (for a variety of reasons)

*'Audit' model with name:string and data:jsonb*

**Audit.rb**

```
store_accessor :data, :publisher, :display_version
```

Then try:

```
Parent.audits.pluck(:name, :publisher, :display_version)
```

---

**[Good Resource on JSONB and Postgresql](http://nandovieira.com/using-postgresql-and-jsonb-with-ruby-on-rails)**

> hstore columns don’t allow a nested structure; they also store all values as strings, which will require type coercion on both database and application layers. With json/jsonb columns you don’t have this problem; numbers (integers/float), booleans, arrays, strings and nulls are accepted, and you can even nest structures in any way you want.
>
> The recommendation is that you stop using hstore in favor of jsonb;
>   just remember that you have to use PostgreSQL 9.4+ for this to work.

Comment: Useful information but it doesn't answer the question.